# How to check two time period for overlap in django?

Tags: python, django

I have a model called slots, I want to check that no slot should overlap one other.

```
class Slot(models.Model):
    start_time = models.TimeField()
    end_time = models.TimeField()
```

For e.g., Say I insert one with start time and end time as 02:00:00 - 03:00:00 now I want to check that all the new incoming start time and end time do not fall between this time slot.
It should also accept the below timeslot as well.
01:00:00 to 02:00:00 and 03:00:00 to 04:00:00 should be acceptable.

P.S. Please see my first try on solving this issue.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Model.objects.filter(
            start_time__lt=new_slot_end_time,
            end_time__gt=new_slot_start_time,
        )

Comment: Your attempt seems to be unrelated to your question. You have to update one of them, with details preferably.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Q object to do this query.

```
from django.db.models import Q

overlapping_slots = Slot.objects.filter(
    Q(start_time__lt=new_start_time, end_time__gt=new_start_time) | 
    Q(start_time__lt=new_end_time, end_time__gt=new_end_time)
)

if overlapping_slots.exists():
    # invalidate the form here
```

Basically you are checking if there are any Slots in the DB where new_start_time is between the start and end times of that slot, and where new_end_time is between the start and end time of that slot.
documentation for Q objects: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects